# codeblocks package broken, how do I remove it so I can install software?

Tags: installation, package-management

I recently installed codeblocks and ever since my software center has stopped working, preventing me from installing or uninstalling other software. All this is caused by unmet dependencies, which I have tried fixing by using `sudo apt-get -f install`. It doesn't work though, and this is shown:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  codeblocks
Suggested packages:
  libwxgtk2.8-dev wx-common codeblocks-contrib
The following packages will be upgraded:
  codeblocks
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,646 kB of archives.
After this operation, 897 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of codeblocks:
 codeblocks depends on libcodeblocks0 (= 10.05-1); however:
  Version of libcodeblocks0 on system is 10.05-2.
 codeblocks depends on codeblocks-common (= 10.05-1); however:
  Version of codeblocks-common on system is 10.05-2.
dpkg: error processing codeblocks (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 codeblocks
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I would very much appreciate it if someone could help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fixed it with `apt-get remove codeblocks`

Answer (score 1):

To fix it, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get remove codeblocks
```

Thanks to [Juan David Castillo](https://askubuntu.com/users/57042/juan-david-castillo) for providing the answer.